# Replacing a "time" column with corresponding values

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, perl

I have a file in the following format:

```
"2004-04-19 12:25:57" 44 44
"2004-04-19 13:39:32" 36 36
"2004-04-19 14:00:53" 34 34
```

I need 2 new files:

a) A file which will replace "time" values of the first column of my file with numbers starting from 1, like this:

```
1 44 44
2 36 36
3 34 34
```

b) Another file which will replace "time" values of the first column of file with numbers unix tamestamp data, like this:

```
1082377557 44 44
1082381972 36 36
1082383253 34 34
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this `bash` one liner :

```
i=1; while IFS=' ' read a b c; do echo "$i $c" >>foo.txt; ((i+=1)); \
     echo "$(date -d "${a#\"} ${b%\"}" '+%s')" "$c" >>bar.txt; done <file.txt
```

Expanded form :

```
i=1
while IFS=' ' read a b c; do 
    echo "$i $c" >>foo.txt
    ((i+=1))
    echo "$(date -d "${a#\"} ${b%\"}" '+%s')" "$c" >>bar.txt
done <file.txt
```

After the operation `foo.txt` will have :

```
1 44 44
2 36 36
3 34 34
```

and `bar.txt` will have :

```
1082377557 44 44
1082381972 36 36
1082383253 34 34
```

Comment: foo.txt was created right, but bar.txt isn't getting filled with anything, instead i get following output at shell.......................................................  -bash:  echo: command not found
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
-bash:  echo: command not found
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
-bash:  echo: command not found
...

Comment: @Haos I have tested this in my Ubuntu 14.04..works fine..what OS are you using ? what does `type -a echo` say ?

Comment: echo is a shell builtin
echo is /bin/echo
echo is /bin/echo

Comment: it seems there is a problem with date command in Mac

Answer (score 1):

awk:

```
awk '{
    # store the time value (first 2 words)
    timestamp = $1 " " $2

    # shift the other fields 2 places (I wish this was simpler in awk)
    for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) $(i-2) = $i
    NF -= 2

    # print to the line-numbers file
    print NR, $0  > "file1"

    # convert the timestamp and print to that file
    gsub(/[-:"]/, " ", timestamp)
    print mktime(timestamp), $0   > "file2"
}' file
```

`mktime` requires GNU awk (I think).

perl:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -anE '
    BEGIN {
        $, = " "; 
        open $f1, ">", "file1"; 
        open $f2, ">", "file2"
    } 
    $date = shift @F; 
    $time = shift @F; 
    say $f1 $., @F; 
    say $f2 Time::Piece->strptime("$date $time", "\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"")->epoch, @F
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Well at the risk of doing your homework for you. Here you are.

Assuming your data is in a file named YOURFILENAME this first oneliner with add the line numbers and the two last fields from the  file

```
count=1;cut -d" " -f 3,4 YOURFILENAME| while read line ; do echo $count $line;((++count)); done
```

This second one-liner will convert your dates to epochs and print out the rest of the line (had to add one more sed to get rid of the quote marks but I did this quick and dirty)

```
cut -d"\"" -f2 YOURFILENAME| while read line; do SWAP=$(date -d "$line" +\%s); sed -i "s/$line/$SWAP/g" YOURFILENAME;done ; sed 's/"//g' YOURFILENAME
```

Please realize that this is just one way that you can do this. There are probably quite a few more.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

#open our files for output
open( my $output1, '>', "output_file_one.txt" ) or die $!;
open( my $output2, '>', "output_file_two.txt" ) or die $!;

#iterate the magic filehandle - <> - which reads either data piped from
#stdin, or opens files specified on command line. (Just like grep/awk/sed)
while (<>) {

    #regex match the values out of your source file.
    my ( $t, @values ) = m/^\"(.*)\" (\d+) (\d+)/;

    #convert $t into a time object.
    $t = Time::Piece->strptime( $t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" );

    #use the "epoch" method to extract the numeric time from $t
    print {$output1} join( " ", $t->epoch, @values );

    # $. is the perl special var for current line number.
    print {$output2} join( " ", $., @values );
}

close($output1);
close($output2);
```